# How does one configure a failover license server in Mathematica?

Tags: licensing

Suppose that I have two different license servers, and I would like Mathematica to attempt to authenticate with server A (say, at lm01.institution.edu) first, and if that one doesn't have any licenses left then to go to server B (say, at lm02.institution.edu).

If I understand correctly, on a standard installation on linux this can be achieved by making sure that the file `~/.Mathematica/Licensing/mathpass` reads

```
!lm01.institution.edu
!lm02.institution.edu
```

in that order. However, I'm less sure how to do that configuration on Windows: I ran `SystemOpen[$UserBaseDirectory]` and it successfully opened a `Mathematica` directory with a `Licensing` folder inside it, but there was nothing in that folder. **What is the equivalent procedure on Windows, then?**

(And, while we're here, if the MacOS procedure differs from the linux way to do this, it'd probably be great if people can note it here as well.)

Comment: `$PasswordFile` should point there and it does for me.